# Form alignment problems

Tags: css

I'm having difficulty aligning elements on my form and need some help. CSS is not a strength of mine!

I want to align "Capacity" and "Week" - along with the sliders to the right of "Park", "Lecture Style" and "Room Structure". (i.e. as a new column)

Secondly I want to equally align the checkboxes properly in rows of 4.

Here is my code so far, I've included a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rRDpj/):

```
<div id="search-1">
    <label>Park</label>
    <select name="">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Lecture Style</label>
    <select name="">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Room Structure</label>
    <select name="">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Capacity</label>
    <input type="text" class="slider_text" disabled="disabled"
    />
    <br />
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <label>Week</label>
    <input type="text" class="slider_text2" disabled="disabled"
    />
    <br />
    <div class="slider2"></div>
    <label>Facilities</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Chalk board
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Computer
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Data projector
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Dual data projector
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Induction loop
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Microphone
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">OHP
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Review
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Visualiser
    <input type="checkbox" name="fac">Wheelchair access</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a first try: http://jsfiddle.net/h4Xxs/

- 2 columns (floating div with 50% width each)
- each label was put in a `label` element when it wasn't already the case
- each label was associated with its form element via `for`/`id` attributes (you can click on a label, that will select its form element. And it's more accessible)
- bunch of radio buttons in a fieldset with a legend. Without a border and with the legend on the legend, you wouldn't recognize the well-known grey border with legend put above it. The fieldset has `clear: both` via the class `.clear` as the 2 previous `div` are floating.
- all radio buttons and their new labels are in a div that won't go under the floating legend because this div is creating a formatting context via `overflow: hidden` (otherwise the second line of radio buttons would begin right under the legend, as you are used to see text to the right and then below an `img { float: left }` in most texts)
- 4 columns of radio buttons but it's not perfect as one label needs 2 lines with your existing width of 8em on each label. Not sure of what it should look like, so I only aligned the `span`s added earlier vertically to top (it's really ugly otherwise). Feel free to modify their layout to your needs.

And that's it. Err, remove all the outlines I added, they're only there for better understanding!

HTML:

```
<div id="search-1">
    <div class="left w50">
        <p>
            <label for="a1">Park</label>
            <select name="" id="a1">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="a2">Lecture Style</label>
            <select name="" id="a2">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="a3">Room Structure</label>
            <select name="" id="a3">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="left w50">
        <p>
            <label for="b1">Capacity</label>
            <input type="text" class="slider_text" disabled="disabled" id="b1">
        </p>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <label for="b2">Week</label>
        <input type="text" class="slider_text2" disabled="disabled" id="b2"
        />
        <div class="slider2"></div>
    </div>

    <fieldset class="clear">
        <legend>Facilities</legend>
        <div class="item">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch1"><label for="ch1">Chalk board</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch2"><label for="ch2">Computer</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch3"><label for="ch3">Data projector</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch4"><label for="ch4">Dual data projector</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch5"><label for="ch5">Induction loop</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch6"><label for="ch6">Microphone</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch7"><label for="ch7">OHP</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch8"><label for="ch8">Review</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch9"><label for="ch9">Visualiser</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fac" id="ch10"><label for="ch10">Wheelchair access</label>
        </span>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    outline: 1px dotted green;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.w50 {
    width: 50%;
}

label {
    width: 8em;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
select {
    width: 12em;
}
.slider, .slider2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
input {
    border: none;
    font-family:'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

fieldset {
    border: none;
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
fieldset > legend {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
fieldset .item {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
fieldset span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    outline: 1px dashed red;
}
fieldset label {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```